How to make an operator form of Part[] to use with // (Postfix)
I've often found myself chaining multiple functions in Mathematica using the // postfix form, and then needing to extract specific parts of the result. The standard approach involves using parentheses and [[]] notation, which can make the code less readable. Additionally, I often don't plan ahead and include the parentheses from the beginning, requiring me to go back and wrap them, which is annoying.
For example, consider the following sequence of function applications:
expr = Range[10];
result = (expr // ftn1 // ftn2 // ftn3)[[2 ;; 5]]

I think sometimes that can be both less readable, and more tedious if you have to retroactively put in the parentheses. I would very much like a operator form of Part that I can add to the chain.
result = expr // ftn1 // ftn2 // ftn3//part[2;;5]

Can we do this in a concise enough syntax to be worth it while keeping all the power of using ;; aka Span?
I searched for duplicates but did not see any, feel free to close this question if I missed anything.

One alternative to putting in the parentheses is, for example, Range[10] // #[[3;;5]]&.  Arguably, it is unreadable, but it does not require searching for matching parentheses or defining a new function.

Or the (perhaps?) more readable Range[10] // Function[el, el[[3 ;; 5]]]

Yes, this is actually surprisingly easy! We simply do the most obvious thing.
part[spec__] := Part[#, spec] &

This works as desired (mostly, see later comment), for example
ftn1[x_] := x^2
ftn2[x_] := x + 1
ftn3[x_] := Sqrt[x]
expr = Range[10];
result = expr // ftn1 // ftn2 // ftn3 // part[2 ;; 5]
(*Expected output:{Sqrt[5],Sqrt[10],Sqrt[17],Sqrt[26]}*)

Additionally, it works for all versions of ;; i.e. Span:
(*Test cases for each Span definition*)
arr = Range[10];
test1 = arr // part[2 ;; 5] (*Expected:{2,3,4,5}*)
test2 = arr // part[6 ;;] (*Expected:{6,7,8,9,10}*)
test3 = arr // part[;; 4] (*Expected:{1,2,3,4}*)
test4 = arr // part[ ;; ] (*Expected:{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}*)
test5 = arr // part[2 ;; 8 ;; 2] (*Expected:{2,4,6,8}*)
test6 = arr // part[3 ;; ;; 3] (*Expected:{3,6,9}*)
test7 = arr // part[;; 7 ;; 2] (*Expected:{1,3,5,7}*)
test8 = arr // part[;; ;; 4] (*Expected:{1,5,9}*)
test9 = arr // part[{1, 3, 4}] (*Expected:{1,3,4}*)

and it precedence is convenient for using Map infix form /@
f /@ {1, 2, 3} // part[1 ;; 2] (*expected output: {f[1],f[2]}*)

Edit 1 (& 3 thank you Kuba)
The one conspicuous failure is that using lists to
specify elements does not work when combined with Span:
arr = Range[{10, 10, 10, 10, 10}];
arr // part[{1, 4}, ;; 5](*fails*)
arr // part[3, {1, 4}](*fails*)
arr // part[3] // part[{1, 4}](*sequential application works*)

My Mistake!! as Kuba pointed out in the comments, using spec__ in the definition fixes this, I believe completely
I'm using version 14.1
Edit 2
I just discovered that GeneralUtilities`Slice seems to be even more what I want, as it has the addition flexibility to do the cases that failed with my method above. The usage message states "Slice[...] represents an operator form of Part". But this is different from the similar answer provided by @Domen using OperatorApplied
part1[spec__] := Part[#, spec] &;
part2 = GeneralUtilities`Slice;
dat = Range[{5, 5, 5}];
dat // part1[{2, 3}, 2 ;; 4](*now works with Kubas modification*)
dat // part2[{2, 3}, 4 ;; 8](*works*)

Of course, as with all undocumented functions, this may be subject to change in the future.
I also found an attempt to implement this as ResourceFunction["Slice"] found here by Taliesin Beynon. But I had to restart the kernel to get that to load successfully. I'm not sure why because I don't use resource functions often, I much prefer to just copy the source code and put them in my own packages. I haven't tested ResourceFunction["Slice"] but I have looked at its code and it also depends on things in GeneralUtilities.

(+1) In addition Query[2 ;; 5]  apparently uses GeneralUtilitiesSlice[2 ;; 5] 'under the hood'.  (Query[2 ;; 5] // Normal`)

And Range[10] // Query[11 ;;] gives the empty set, unlike Range[10] // Query[11], (as pointed out by @Sjoerd Smit in his answer)

Don't you need double _ for part1?

thank you @Kuba! Ican't believe I missed that...

@user1066 i didn't even know using Normal on an expression like that would be useful!

If you like a more functional approach, there is OperatorApplied.
part = OperatorApplied[Part];

{a, b, c, d} // part[4]
(* d *)

{a, b, c, d} // part[2 ;; 3]
(* b, c *)


Query can be used for this:
Range[10] // Query[2 ;; 5]

Note that Query behaves slightly different for non-existing elements:
Range[10] // Query[5 ;; 12]
Range[10] // Query[12]


{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}


Missing["PartAbsent", 12]

